# Menu: On hover toggle div slide from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a slide down menu that opens when hovering .account-nav-show. I have done the slide down function, but it wont slide back up when you remove your arrow from .account-nav-show. Also, What I'm trying to do is to make it stay open until you take your arrow down into the actual #account-nav. Any ideas?

Also, the div where the .account-nav-show is, has a :hover, so it changes color when you hover the .account-nav-show. Is it possible to keep it at :hover when you slide the arrow down into the #account-nav?

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#account-nav").hide();
        $(".account-nav-show").show();

    $('.account-nav-show').hover(function(){
    $("#account-nav").slideDown(400);
    });

});

</script>
<a class="account-nav-show">Account</a> 
<div id="account-nav">
<a href="/account">Account</a><br>
{{ 'Log out' | customer_logout_link }} 
</div>
```

Comment: You are getting any error in console?

Answer (score 1):

Add this after hover binding:

```
$('.account-nav-show').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $("#account-nav").slideUp(400);
});
```

Here is final code you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#account-nav").hide();
        $(".account-nav-show").show();

        $('.account').hover(function(){
            $("#account-nav").slideDown(400);
        });

        $('.account').on('mouseleave', function(){
            $("#account-nav").slideUp(400);
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="account">
    <a href="#" class="account-nav-show">Account</a> 
    <div id="account-nav">
        <a href="/account">Account</a><br>
        {{ 'Log out' | customer_logout_link }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

There is JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/odorcxeu/

Comment: Can't get it to work...


`$(document).ready(function(){
 
        $("#account-nav").hide();
        $(".account-nav-show").show();
 
    $('.account-nav-show').hover(function(){
    $('.account-nav-show').blur(function(){
    $("#account-nav").slideUp(400);
});
    $("#account-nav").slideDown(400);
    });
  
 
});`

Comment: Oh, sorry, i tell you wrong event, you need "mouseleave" of cause.

Comment: Thanks! But this worked: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#account-nav").hide();
        $(".account-nav-show").show();

        $('.account-nav-show').hover(function(){
            $("#account-nav").slideDown(400);
        });

        $('#account-nav').on('mouseleave', function(){
            $("#account-nav").slideUp(400);
        });
    });
</script>` @Zav

Comment: go to [link](www.eldeskin.com) and check out the account link. do you see the hovering effect on the div with all the links? can i make that stay until the mousearrow have been removed from #account-nav?

Comment: Take a look at example on jsfiddle. Also there is no access to your site.